# Access Android's system fonts in webview

Tags: android, ios, css

So iOS allows users to tap into the system font settings (dynamic type) using css for cordova apps. [This article](http://mir.aculo.us/2013/09/16/how-to-create-a-web-app-that-looks-like-a-ios7-native-app-part-1/) explains the process. The end result being css that looks like so.

```
h1 {
  font-family: -apple-system-font;
}
```

This is a powerful feature to have and I was wondering if Android had the same thing? I had read some articles that suggested this approach

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'RobotoRegular', 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

But it provides no changes. Anyone have any idea if this possible with android 4.0 and up?

Comment: Shouldn't `font-family: sans-serif` use the default system font?

Comment: derp, totally forgot about that trick! Thanks, can you put this as an answer and I'll mark it correct?

Comment: just added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use the default system font with the following:

```
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: font-family: serif; // works for me but sans-serif not working

Answer (score -1):

Not very pretty code, but this is how I achieved it:

```
body{
    font-family: HelveticaLight;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/HelveticaLight.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaLight';
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/HelveticaLight.ttf') format('woff'),
        url('file:///android_asset/fonts/HelveticaLight.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('file:///android_asset/fonts/HelveticaLight.ttf') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Not really what I was asking for. Basically I want to know if I can use the built in system fonts on android like I can on iOS